# What is the earliest version of Windows that runs Node.js?

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-7, windows-8.1, windows-xp

A web search has not turned up any statement I could tell that said that Node.js runs for Version A of Windows or more recent, but is not supported by Version B or older.

What is the earliest version of Windows that runs Node.js? What's the latest version that doesn't?

Comment: Is anything before XP even relevant? And it will be updated to support the latest, so that's irrelevant / too time-specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this post on the nodejs blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/06/23/porting-node-to-windows-with-microsoft%25e2%2580%2599s-help/), the initial effort to port node.js to Windows supported versions back to Windows Server 2003.  I don't find any more current info on that.  There are both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of nodejs for Windows so it supports both options there too.

And, nodejs is regularly updated to run on the latest versions of Windows so that should not be an issue unless you are trying to run an early beta of Windows that has not been around for long.